# return pointer from a C function is good/bad design?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static, return

I want to know if return pointer from a C function is good/bad design? If it is a bad practice, what would be a good practice in the following example:

The question is a continued part of:
[c function return static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621760/c-function-return-static-variable)

in `data.h` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct
{
   int age;
   int number;
} person;

person * getPersonInfo();
```

in `data.c`

```
#include "data.h"
static struct person* person_p = NULL;

person * getPersonInfo()
{
   person_p = (struct person*)malloc(10 * sizeof(struct person));
   return person_p;
}
```

in `main.c`

```
#include "data.h"

int main()
{
   person* pointer = getPersonInfo();
   return 0;
}
```

basically, the `main` function in `main` file needs to get the value of all the elements of array which is pointed by static pointer `person_p`, if it is not a good practice, then what a good practice should be?

Comment: If you have a function that performs a `malloc`, you should also have a matching function to do `free()`, even if it is just a wrapper. It is bad design to call `free(pointer)` in your `main` - Which you're not doing in the example, thus leaking memory...kinda.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer and is a big part of the standard lib. What do you think?

Comment: How would you get along in any non-trivial program in C without that??

Comment: Close voters: Seriously, if people think good/bad program design is "opinion-based" or _"the arts"_, then you need to get out of the garage and get some proper programming education. What's good and bad program design is _not_ opinion-based, there is plenty of research on the topic and there is plenty of consensus among programmers all around the world. If people can't ask program design questions on SO, then I don't know what can be asked here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason it is bad is because you don't have any memory managing structure behind it. In your current code, you have a memory leak because you allocate a `person` struct via malloc() but do not free it.

Consider writing a wrapper function that handles that memory management for you like so:

```
void freePerson(struct person * personToDelete)
{
    free(personToDelete);
}
```

Then in your main:

```
int main()
{
   person* pointer = getPersonInfo();
   freePerson(pointer); // After you are done using it
   return 0;
}
```

I also have to warn against casting the results of `malloc()`. In my experience it can result in undefined behavior.

Comment: what is the wrapper looks like, I do not know about it

Comment: It's not necessarily bad - it just transfers the responsibility for freeing the allocated memory to the caller

Comment: Which is bad design, because the caller shouldn't be assumed to free those structures.

Comment: @IshayPeled Unless you are writing your own memory allocation routine or some such, then that is _bad design_ and one of the most common causes for memory leaks in all software released the last decades.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to return pointers to private variables. Also, with the current design, your .c file can only have one instance of the person object.

And almost needless to say, the same code which dynamically allocates an object should also be responsible of freeing it. Code which is written so that some other module in the program is expected to clean up the mess always ends up with memory leaks, per design.

If you are writing an at least somewhat complex data type, where you need to restrict access to private variables, have multiple instances of the struct etc, then it is good practice to use "opaque type" instead. Example (not tested):

// data.h

```
#ifndef DATA_H 
#define DATA_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct person person; // opaque type

person* person_create (void);

void person_delete (person* p);

void person_set_age (person* p, int age);
int  person_get_age (const person* p);
// ... and so on, setters/getters

#endif // DATA_H
```

// data.c

```
#include "data.h"

struct
{
  int age;
  int number;
} person;    


person* person_create (void)
{
  return malloc(sizeof(struct person));
}

void person_delete (person* p)
{
  free(p);
}

void person_set_age (person* p, int age)
{
  p->age = age;
}

int person_get_age (const person* p)
{
  return p->age;
}
```

// caller:

```
#include "data.h"

int main()
{
   person* p = person_create();

   person_set_age(p, 50);
   printf("%d", person_get_age(p));

   person_delete(p);
   return 0;
}
```

Some things to consider:

- Always use header guards in h files.
- Never use empty parameter list `()` for C functions (but always do in C++).
- Don't cast the result of malloc in C (but always do in C++).
- There needs to be some error handling added to this code in case malloc fails.

Comment: somehow, the data.c is used to keep all the data needed by the program, and then the main function in main file will fetch the needed data from the data.c file, in your example, looks like the data is kept in caller file? And how about if the person is a array?

Comment: @ratzip With this approach, everything is allocated by the data.c file and only that file knows what to do with it. The actual data is stored on the heap... not in a file. If you want an array, simply `person* p[n];` and call the create function in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of decision more than everything else.

Both options are valid as long as you're aware of each pro's and con's

Returning pointer pros:

1. Encapsulation of memory allocation
2. Support dynamic memory sizes on the fly

Returning pointer cons:

1. only one possible out parameter
2. Memory has to be allocated on the heap every time

Accepting pointer as input pros are exactly the opposite:

1. multiple out parameters
2. Memory does not have to be allocated on the heap, the caller can use a variable on it's stack to use as output parameter

Accepting pointer as input cons:

1. No encapsulation of memory allocation
2. No support for dynamic memory sizes on the fly - sizes must be fixed or pre-specified

In your specific example, I'd use an output parameter as it is fixed size and can easily be called without allocating memory dynamically.

Comment: what is the encapsulation you mean, this is in C

Comment: Encapsulation is a term not specific to OOP - you encapsulate the memory allocation in the function you use to calculate it

Comment: "only one possible out parameter" Err... no? C has pointers. Passing parameters by pointers is everyday C programming. Pointer-to-pointers exist pretty much for the sole reason of returning dynamic memory through a parameter. "Memory has to be allocated on the heap every time". No, you can write static memory pools or use alloca or similar. And where memory is allocated is not really related to the program design.

Comment: @IshayPeled Encapsulation _is_ a term specific to OOP, but **OO design has nothing to do with language choice**. Some languages have support for OO features, but just because they do, it doesn't necessarily mean that your program turns OO just because you program in a language with such features. Similarly, you can use OO design when writing C programs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c

Comment: Lyndon - encapsulation is a term in the English language, please look it up and see what I meant by encapsulating memory allocation. If you return the memo

Answer (score 0):

To be a good design you must have a matching function that frees the allocated memory when it is no longer needed.